# Mod rewrite to redirect a remote resource to a local folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to setup my localhost to redirect absolute urls from a specific subdomain to local paths using mod_rewrite as follow:

```
http://resources.website.com/img/mypic.gif
```

would redirect to

```
/Users/path-to-local-website/img/mypic.gif
```

so my local HTML could read

```
<img src="http://resources.website.com/img/mypic.gif" />
```

and yet refer to the local image.

What would be the RewriteCond/Rule for that? Thank you

Comment: You control `resources.website.com`?

Comment: I think you need to give us some more details. Are we talking about several different servers here? What would be the connection?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question and sorry if I wasn't very clear. My website is up on a domain and subdomains that I own, but I want to keep a fully functional offline copy on my computer. Certain pages of the site call for resources using absolute path to subdomains that I own, like images.mywebsite.com/mypic.gif, and I would like to setup my local apache conf file to rewrite those links to point to the local folder where the images were created. I thought mod_rewrite could do the job but I'm not familiar with the syntax. Any help with that would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have websites hosted somewhere in the cloud, and local replicas thereof where you do the development The HTML is the same, of course. You upload that without modifications. It contains absolute references to documents among your domains, such as images.

When surfing the local copy of this website, you want images to come from the local copies rather than from the cloud?

Sorry, I don't think that is possible, at least not with `mod_rewrite`. Your local server is feeding your browser URL's which point back to the cloud. When your browser processes theses URL's, it will send the request off to the real website. You cannot rewrite a request that went to some other server!

You would have to filter the HTML that is going out to rewrite the URL's so that those domains point back to the local server.

If only one domain is involved, the usual solution is not to use absolute links in the HTML, just ones relative to that web page. (For any links that don't cross domains, you should use make them page relative.)

A solution would be to create a local test bed environment with its own DNS server sitting on your LAN which will resolve those domain names to your local server. Your browser is thereby fooled into going to your local server for those domains.

If your browser is on Linux or other Unix-like OS, you can simiply hack this with `/etc/hosts` rather than a complex DNS setup:

```
# /etc/hosts on the machine where the browser and server are running
127.0.0.1 foo.example.com bar.example.com xyzzy.example.com
```

Now these three host names point back to the server. When your browser (running on the same machine) wants to fetch `foo.example.com/img/dog.jpg` it will connect to the server at `127.0.0.1`.

Configure that server with an `Alias` to forward the `/img/` URL's as appropriate:

```
# httpd.conf
Alias /img/ /Users/path-to-local-website/img/
```

But now, you are only seeing the local site. Not just the images. Everything is locally referenced.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I thought of modifying /etc/hosts but I would not be able to display the remote website on that machine anymore. I was hoping to find a solution that would deduct where to get the content from the url. You must be right, it's not possible since the browser handles the images/css/js requests. Thanks again

Comment: You can have this set up in a virtual machine. Browse in the host OS, and you see the deployed website. Browse in the guest OS, and `/etc/hosts` lets you browse the development one.

Comment: Or,  heck, a `chroot`-ed environment within the same OS image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. These are suitable solutions. I will look into them. I appreciate your stellar understanding of the problem. Best

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using mod_rewrite as long as you can plan an .htaccess on the domain: `resources.website.com`. Put this code in .htaccess file under DOCUMENT_ROOT of `resources.website.com`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(img/.*)$ http://localhost/$1 [R,L]
```

And make sure that `img/` folder and its content is there in DOCUMENT_ROOT on your localhost.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. You have an interesting idea here, but I'm looking for something that would work offline (internet disconnected) and allow me to display the web content (img/js/css) from my local machine without changing the absolute urls in the html. It's looking hard to achieve. Thanks again though

Comment: If that is the case then putting a record in `/etc/hosts` is the best option you have.